# I can't import my existing project in Android Studio using Mac os

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-layout

I switched my os windows to Mac os after installing android studio on mac os I can't import projects in android studio

I want this type of popup on my mac screen when clicking on import project
[image]

But Studio show this screen was not showing a green android project icon
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not use  Files>import.

Try use Files>open.

It sometimes happens when the some files in .idea folder is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Export feature to copy your projects. Go to `File > Export > Export to Zip File`.  (Photo 1)

Copy that Zip File to your other PC. Extract it. And Then Open it with  `File > Open > Browse the Project Folder`.

I hope that helps.

Photo 1

[image: 1]]

Photo 2

[image: 2]]